# Compare time part of time stamp to see if it is between a range - in a dataframe in Python and return a new column with True/False

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I am relatively new to pyton and struggling with something that i feel should be straight forward.

I have a dataframe with a timestamp and I want to check to see if it is between 11pm and 6am and if it is then mark it as true, otherwise false.

I have tried a number of approaches - below shows one approach where i am extracting the time and comparing to the 11pm and I am getting an error

````
df['VOUCHER_TRANSACTION_DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df['VOUCHER_TRANSACTION_DATE'])
df['transaction_time']=df['VOUCHER_TRANSACTION_DATE'].dt.time

df['Status'] = df.apply (
    lambda df : (
      'true' 
          if df['transaction_time']> datetime.time(23,0) 
       else 'false'
    ) ,
    axis = 1
)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `hour` to get the hour part of the datetime(s).

```py
df['Status'] = df.apply(
    lambda df : (
          df['VOUCHER_TRANSACTION_DATE'].hour > 23 & df['VOUCHER_TRANSACTION_DATE'].hour < 6
    ),
    axis = 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks Norie. works if i put in VOUCHER_TRANSACTION_DATE instead of transaction_time!

Comment: Ah, I thought you had renamed the column.